# How to decrypt .REM File without Blackberry

Tags: encryption, blackberry

I found my old microSDHC Card that had been encrypted with Blackberry 9220 when the phone still can be used (now dead). I still remember the password, but I dont have any idea how to decrypt it to a Non-Blackberry platform. Is there any solution? Thx in advance.

Comment: for photos, generally, you can just change the extension. eg: photo.jpg.rem becomes photo.jpg and it'll be vieweable. However, that doesn't work on all files. https://www.forensicfocus.com/forums/mobile-forensics/rem-blackberry-files/

Comment: https://www.elcomsoft.com/help/en/eppb/index.html?decrypt_bleckberry_sd_card.html but that is quite expensive https://www.elcomsoft.com/eppb.html

Comment: @Gantendo when I choose the Blackberry folder, it is not responding. Theres no popup to insert password like the guide

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, but I don't have the SD card anymore, I just have the files in .REM with the hope one day I can access my files again.

I have looking wherever for a solution, I can tell you that if you can fix your BB without formatting the BB and you will have access to it in the same BB.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1127423)